# Custom iOS Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikeyboard

I want to add a *keyboard* icon to the bottom left grey square on `UIKeyboardType.NumberPad`. How can this be done?

Some ideas I have went through.

- `class` that conforms to `UITextInputTraits` I couldn't figure out what was required to satisfy the protocol.
- `UIButton` above the keyboard
- `subclass` of `UIView` and not use a keyboard at all. This one seems the hardest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a custom view in the bottom, you have to add a subview to the keyboards window view so it overlays the keyboard.

The Keyboard is shown on a separate window `UIRemoteKeyboardWindow`

Run this code AFTER the keyboard gets shown:

```
    let view = UIButton(frame: yourFrame)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.last?.addSubview(view)
```

It's the cleanest solution that requires the least work.

Comment: I tried that and I could only get it to be above the keyboard in a bar. I want it in the bottom left corner where their currently is a blank grey rectangle.

Comment: let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 40, width: 80, height: 40);       
let view = UIView(frame: frame);
view.backgroundColor = MDColor().black;
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.addSubview(view)   This doesn't work.

Comment: You're right. The keyboard is shown on a separate window, so you have to add a subview to THAT window. http://grab.by/MKB0

Comment: It was under the keyboard.

Comment: I edited the code. You have to get the last window, not the key window.

Comment: Hey Cody, can you award the bounty? Thanks.

Comment: I thought I did. Yes you completely deserve it. How can I do it.

Comment: haha, just press the grayed out bounty on the left: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/images/wordpress/bounty-award-indicators.png

Comment: Do you know how to remove the button?

Comment: What button ? The button you added ? removeFromSuperview